# In clojure, how to make a search procedure return as soon as the answer is found

Tags: search, clojure, functional-programming

Clojure newbie here.

I was solving a searching problem in Clojure.
In search problem, it's quite common to return early as soon as the answer is found.
For example, in Java

```
boolean search(State x) {
  if (finishState(x)) return true;
  for (State y: expand(x)) {
    if (search(y)) return true; // Return early
  }
}
```

I was stuck how to implement this in Clojure, since Clojure does not have return statement.
I have to map all the results for each expanding state of x and see if there's a true in there. But this approach does not make use of the short-circuit and have bad performance since it go through all the search tree.

```
(some true? (map search (expand x)))
```

The `or` macro does not help here, and I know the existence of `lazy-seq`, but 
is it really necessary? What's the ideal way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` returns a lazy sequence;

When you use `some true?`, that lazy sequence will be consumed incrementally, calling `search` on the first element, then the second (if needed), then the third (if needed), ... etc until the first time `search` returns `true`.

So it uses "short-circuiting" by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to find one element, use `reduce` together with `reduced`.

```
(reduce (fn [_ elem]
           (if (pred elem)
             (reduced elem))) 
        nil input)
```

`pred` is assumed to be a function that returns a `non-nil value` when it is invoked with the desired element.

Notice that the lambda argument to reduce takes a (in the above example unused and hence bound as `_`) first accumulator argument. It is rebound at each step to what the lambda returned last time so in case you have not found the desired element, you can use the lambdas return value to track values for the next step.

Notice that `reduced` returns a special value that lets `reduce` stop consuming the input immediately.

As far as I am concerend this strategy usually gives the best performance in direct comparison to both lazy sequence filtering and looping.